# custom button on android studio 4.2

Tags: android, xml, button

I am new on android studio and trying to customise my buttons, I created a new xml file in the folder drawable but **solid** and **padding** properties doesn't work...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#69EA64"/>
    <size android:height="100dp"
        android:width="150dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    <padding android:bottom="60dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="#FF0"
        android:width="5dp"
        android:dashGap="3dp"
        android:dashWidth="15dp"/>
    <gradient android:angle="45"
        android:startColor="#FF00"
        android:centerColor="#49A530"
        android:endColor="#FF0"/>
</shape>
```

And this is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please help...

Comment: kindly post your XML code as well.

Answer (score 1):

to make working `solid`, remove `gradient`

to make `padding` use `inset` instead. Whole code to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="60dp">

    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#69EA64" />
        <size
            android:width="150dp"
            android:height="100dp" />
        <corners android:radius="50dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="5dp"
            android:color="#FF0"
            android:dashWidth="15dp"
            android:dashGap="3dp" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```